# How configure csc from msbuild in command line?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, csc

I have cs0518 error when build solution (console app .net framework 4.6.1 and .net standard 2.0 library for it)  on jenkins(but local build without problems) and try fix it. I found /nostdlib+ csc.exe  param in log and it can be a [reason](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0518) of this error.

Errors only for .net standard library:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AssemblyTitleAttribute' could not be found
error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found
error CS0400: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found in the global namespace
error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported 
...
```

I use MSBuild.exe on jenkins, and it uses csc.exe(so I can not modify csc.exe params directly). I tried modify .csproj: `<NoStdLib>false</NoStdLib>`, but /nostdlib+ exists yet.

How I can [configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/nostdlib-compiler-option) csc.exe from MSBuild.exe tool or resolve this problem in different way?

UPD csc params:

```
csc.exe /noconfig /unsafe- /checked- /nowarn:1701,1702,1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE;DEBUG;NETSTANDARD;NETSTANDARD2_0 /debug+ /debug:portable /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\yyy.dll /target:library /warnaserror- /utf8output /deterministic+ kkk.cs "C:\Windows\TEMP\.NETStandard,Version=v2.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\bbb.AssemblyInfo.cs
```

libs .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

nuget version: `v4.9.3`

msbuild version: `15.9.21.664`

Comment: csc.exe is not called from MSBuild, it uses a different system to configure and invoke compiler components. I'm also sure that your problems are not related to this flag but other csproj file or build system configuration issue. Please try to create a reproducible sample or share details about your projects and build system.

Comment: but csc.exe called (in section CoreCompile) after this comand(I have not explicit call of csc.exe): "...\MSBuild.exe " c:\...\xxx.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU".

Comment: Yes but what are you doing to trigger the error? no targeting pack installed on the build server? can you capture a binlog (-bl flag) to get the arguments that the compile task gets?

Comment: That error only happens when something is missing on the build agent or misconfigured in the csproj. Some projects deliberately tell the compiler not to use the "stdlib" but then provide the necessary references themselves, e.g. .net core projects.

Comment: okay a .net standard project? what does the csproj look like?

Comment: is the project fully restored? which version of msbuild are you using? you are only sharing an error message and some very specific details, but no context to help diagnosing.

Comment: yes restored by msbuild with flag  /t:Restore , msbuild version '15.9.21.664'

Comment: do you call the restore and build target in separate invocations? if not, use `/restore` instead or it will skip some important build logic on first restores (likely to happen on build servers). if this persists, please try to capture a binary log to help understand what is going wrong but see [this information on binary logs](https://gist.github.com/dsplaisted/b256d7804672a6f6375476a5f5658b7b) before.

Comment: .net standard libraries are supported to be built with `/nostdlib` enabled since the involved packages provide additional assemblies containing the types that should be passed using `/r` references to the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed problems by changing pipeline's operation order. 
Needed:

1) `msbuild ... \restore`

2) `nuget restore ...`